# Not able to call registration Intent GCM Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make a messaging app on Android and I want to GCM. But I am not able to get the registrationId. This is my code

```
public static void register(Context context) {
    //Log.v(TAG,"register");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------Authentication Register-----------------------");
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(
            "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    // sets the app name in the intent
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app",
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", SENDER_ID);
    context.startService(registrationIntent);
}

public static void unregister(Context context) {
    Intent unregIntent = new Intent(
            "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
    unregIntent.putExtra("app",
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    context.startService(unregIntent);
}
  }
```

My BroadcastReceiver Class

```
  @Override
public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("------------------------------------BroadCastReceiver---------------------------------");
    MyIntentService.runIntentInService(context, intent);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
}
```

MyIntentService Class

```
 static void runIntentInService(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("--------------------------------Intent---------------------------------");
    synchronized (LOCK) {
        contextC = context;
        if (sWakeLock == null) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            sWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    "my_wakelock");
        }
    }
    sWakeLock.acquire();
    intent.setClassName(context, MyIntentService.class.getName());
    context.startService(intent);
}

@Override
public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------Register-------------------------------------------");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.v("Intent", "RegisterIntent");
        if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
            Log.v("Intent", "RegisterIntent1");
            handleRegistration(intent);
        } else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
            handleMessage(intent);
        } else if (action.equals("com.example.gcm.intent.RETRY")) {
            String token = intent.getStringExtra("token");
            // make sure intent was generated by this class, not by a
            // malicious app
            if (TOKEN.equals(token)) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                        PREFS_NAME, 0);
                String registrationId = settings.getString(
                        "registrationId", null);// get from shared
                                                // properties
                if (registrationId != null) {
                    // last operation was attempt to unregister; send
                    // UNREGISTER intent again
                    Authentication.unregister(this);
                } else {
                    // last operation was attempt to register; send REGISTER
                    // intent again
                    Authentication.register(this);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            sWakeLock.release();
        }
    }
}

private void handleRegistration(Intent intent) {
    String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
    //Log.v("RegistrationId", registrationId);
    String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
    String unregistered = intent.getStringExtra("unregistered");
    // registration succeeded
    if (registrationId != null) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("registrationId", registrationId);
        editor.commit();
        //Log.v("Hello", "Registration Idaiudhaodhafhsofahsfs");
        // store registration ID on shared preferences
        // notify 3rd-party server about the registered ID
    }

    // unregistration succeeded
    if (unregistered != null) {
        // get old registration ID from shared preferences
        // notify 3rd-party server about the unregistered ID
    }

    // last operation (registration or unregistration) returned an error;
    if (error != null) {
        if ("SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE".equals(error)) {
            if ("SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE".equals(error)) {
                long backoffTimeMs = 12;// get back-off time from shared
                                        // preferences
                long nextAttempt = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                        + backoffTimeMs;
                Intent retryIntent = new Intent(
                        "com.example.gcm.intent.RETRY");
                retryIntent.putExtra("token", TOKEN);
                PendingIntent retryPendingIntent = PendingIntent
                        .getBroadcast(contextC, 0, retryIntent, 0);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) contextC
                        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, nextAttempt,
                        retryPendingIntent);
                backoffTimeMs *= 2; // Next retry should wait longer.
                // update back-off time on shared preferences
            } else {
                // Unrecoverable error, log it
                //Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + error);
            }
            // optionally retry using exponential back-off
            // (see Advanced Topics)
        } else {
            // Unrecoverable error, log it
            Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + error);
        }
    }
}

private void handleMessage(final Intent intent) {
    // final String ridesJSON=intent.getStringExtra("rides");
    // System.out.print(ridesJSON);
    Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    //Log.v("Message Chat", intent.getStringExtra("message"));

    h.post(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(contextC, intent.getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    });
    /*
     * h.post(new Runnable(){
     * 
     * @Override public void run() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     */
    // }

    // });
    // server sent 2 key-value pairs, score and time
    // String score = intent.getStringExtra("score");
    // String time = intent.getStringExtra("time");
    // generates a system notification to display the score and time
}
```

My Activity Class

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_detail);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textEmail);
    Authentication.register(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_user_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

public void butSubmitClick(View view) {
    userDetail = new UserDetail();
    userDetail.setId(1);
    userDetail.setName("Nilesh");
    userDetail.setEmail(email.getText() + "");
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    registrationId = settings.getString("registrationId", null);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("email", email.getText() + "");
    editor.commit();
    Log.v("UserDetail ID", registrationId);
    userDetail.setRegistrationId(registrationId);
    Intent intent = new Intent(UserDetailActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    UserDetailActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    new SendUserDetail().execute(userDetail);
}
```

But I always get registration Id as null. I even thought that it may take some time to get registered. But waiting for id haven't helped me

Please, can someone help me out

Answer (score 1):

In mainActivity() call following code:

```
GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
```

this line actually request your GCM to register your device into GCM.
After successful registration, following method of GCMIntentService will be called.

```
@Override protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    // here you will get registrationId.
    // Use this registration id save it safely
    // as you need to use it after for your message passing.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used pattern proposed [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app) in documentation. Lots of things are done by Google library and it worked for me like out of the box. It might me helpful for you.

Comment: I have followed the documentation on this link http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html which has good handling of all cases

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but I cannot see where you actually call the GCMRegistrar class? Something like this:

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
  GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
  Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
}
```

Also, I have created a small open source project that will help you with handling the handling of the registration id. Could perhaps be interesting, check it out at: https://code.google.com/p/gcmutils/